# Из-за чего происходит exception?

Tags: java, javafx, hibernate

Создаю простое приложение для CRUD операций. Использую postgresql+hibernate+java jdk 11+javafx(jfoenix).
Проблема появилась, когда хочу подгрузить данные в таблицу (JFXTreeTableView), для этого необходимо использовать StringProperty и подобные типы данных. Но при первом обращении к hibernate возникает exception. Помогите разобраться с проблемой. листинг и exception прилагаю

```
нояб. 07, 2019 1:27:32 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
    WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 11.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 10.0.2-internal
    нояб. 07, 2019 1:27:45 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
    INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.4.Final}
    нояб. 07, 2019 1:27:58 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
    INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
    нояб. 07, 2019 1:27:59 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
    WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
    нояб. 07, 2019 1:27:59 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
    INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [org.postgresql.Driver] at URL [jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/inventarisation]
    нояб. 07, 2019 1:27:59 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
    INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****, user=postgres}
    нояб. 07, 2019 1:27:59 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
    INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
    нояб. 07, 2019 1:27:59 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
    INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
    нояб. 07, 2019 1:28:00 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
    INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect
    нояб. 07, 2019 1:28:02 PM org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl configure
    INFO: Envers integration enabled? : true
    нояб. 07, 2019 1:28:08 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PoolState stop
    INFO: HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/inventarisation]
    Исключение!org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at service.dao.UserDao.authUser(UserDao.java:19)
        at service.services.UserService.authUser(UserService.java:15)
        at auth.AuthController.authenticateUser(AuthController.java:94)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
        at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1782)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1670)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
        at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8865)
        at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:200)
        at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:206)
        at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
        at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3876)
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1300(Scene.java:3604)
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1874)
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2613)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:395)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:175)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Class User

```java
    import com.jfoenix.controls.datamodels.treetable.RecursiveTreeObject;
    import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
    import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;


    import javax.persistence.*;

    @Entity
    @Table (name = "\"AuthUser\"" , schema = "public")
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    public class User extends RecursiveTreeObject<User> {
        private SimpleIntegerProperty id;
        private SimpleStringProperty login;
        private SimpleStringProperty password;
        //можно не указывать Column name, если оно совпадает с названием столбца в таблице

        public User() {
        }

        public User(Integer id, String name, String password) {
            setId(id);
            setLogin(name);
            setPassword(password);
        }

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
        @Column(name = "\"IdUser\"")
        public int getId() {
            return id.get();
        }
        public void setId(int id){this.id.set(id);}

        @Column(name = "\"LoginUser\"")
        public String getLogin() {
            return login.get();
        }
        public void setLogin(String login){this.login.set(login);}

        @Column(name = "\"PassUser\"")
        public String getPassword(){return password.get();}
        public void setPassword(String password){this.password.set(password);}

        //TODO добавить смену пароля
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "models.User{" +
                    "id=" + id +
                    ", name='" + login + '}';
        }
    }
```

Class UserDAO

```java
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import service.models.User;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import service.utils.HibernateSessionFactoryUtil;

import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;

public class UserDao {

    public boolean authUser(String Login,String Password){
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try(Session session = HibernateSessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()){
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<User> query = builder.createQuery(User.class);
            Root<User> root = query.from(User.class);
            query.select(root).where(builder.equal(root.get("login"), Login)).where(builder.equal(root.get("password"),Password));
            Query<User> q=session.createQuery(query);
            User user=q.getSingleResult();
            if(user!=null){
                transaction.commit();
                return true;
            }else{
                transaction.commit();
                return false;
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            if (transaction != null) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Class UserService

```java
import service.dao.UserDao;
import service.models.User;

import java.util.List;

public class UserService {

    private UserDao usersDao = new UserDao();

    public UserService() {
    }
    public boolean authUser(String login,String password){
        return usersDao.authUser(login,password);
    }
```

Class HibernateSessionFactoryUtil

```java
import service.models.Company;
import service.models.User;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateSessionFactoryUtil {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private HibernateSessionFactoryUtil() {}

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
            try {
                Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
                configuration.addAnnotatedClass(User.class);
                configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Company.class);
                StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
                sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Исключение!" + e);
            }
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Метод в authController

```java
    @FXML
    public void authenticateUser(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        // write your logic to authenticate user
        if(textFieldLogin.getLength()==0 && passField.getLength()==0){
            dialogMenu.DisplayDialogWithOK(stackPane,DialogMenu.TYPE.ERROR.getTitle(),"Не введен логин или пароль!");
            return;
        }else{
            try{
                UserService userService = new UserService();
                if(**userService.authUser(textFieldLogin.getText(),passField.getText())!=false**)
                    new MainFormController().displayHomeScreen(stage);
                else {
                    dialogMenu.DisplayDialogWithOK(stackPane,DialogMenu.TYPE.ERROR.getTitle(),"Неправильный логин или пароль");
                }
            }catch (Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/inventarisation</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">admin</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.8.jre7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <!-- to start need only this -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- for JPA, use hibernate-entitymanager instead of hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- optional -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-osgi</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-proxool</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-infinispan</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--END Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jfoenix</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfoenix</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: У вас проблема с версиями, посмотрите здесь [ответы](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46870715/javafx-warning-with-fxml)

Comment: @Blacit Проблема не в этом, это просто предупреждение и ui даже с ним грузится.....

Comment: так у вас явно `NPE` в 19 строке класса UserDao. Поставьте там брейкпойнт и посмотрите, что именно не инициализировано.
Я вот на глаз посчитал 19ю строку, там есть вызов `CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();`. Проверьте или `session` у вас не `null`.

Comment: А так должно быть, что все эти SimpleStringProperty в User-е нигде не создаются? ДжавуFX не знаю, может правда кто-то по-тихому их создаёт, но выглядит подозрительно.